# In SQL server, how do I output one JSON dictionary?

Tags: json, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with three columns, `docid`, `key` and `value`.
I would like to get one dictionary for a given `docid`.

I tried this:

```
select key, value from mytable where docid=456 for json path
```

But I get this:

```
[{"key":"key1", "value":"value1"}, {"key":"key2","value":"value2"},...]
```

I would like this:

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2",...}
```

`json_object` function does not allow aggregating
Is there a way to accomplish this without defining functions?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to perform a dynamic pivot on your data first; pivoting on all the distinct values in your `key` column, and projecting them as distinct columns. And *then* doing your `for json path, without_array_wrapper`.

Here's an example of how that could work.

```
drop table if exists #data
create table #data
(
    K varchar(30),
    V varchar(30)
)

insert into #data
select 'key1', 'value1' union all
select 'key2', 'value2' union all
select 'key3', 'value3' 

declare 
    @Columns nvarchar(max),
    @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @JSON nvarchar(max)

select @Columns = string_agg(quotename(K), ',')
from #data


select @SQL = 
concat
('
    select @JSON = 
    (
        select ' , @Columns, '
        from #data d
        pivot (max(V) for K in (', @Columns, ')) p
        for json path, without_array_wrapper
    )
')

exec sp_executesql 
    @sql,
    N'@JSON nvarchar(max) output',
    @Json output

select @JSON
```

This outputs

> {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}

Here's another SO article on [dynamic pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query). The concept is the same, you're just wrapping the results in a `for json` call.

Comment: As a matter of best practice, I would recommend using `QUOTENAME()` to make the column names safe against SQL injection attacks, even if the key names are considered trusted. It also nicely handles key names containing spaces, although I am unsure if the resulting JSON would be valid.

Comment: Yep good call thanks

Comment: You can use `STRING_AGG` no dynamic SQL needed. See dupe links

Comment: Crazy. Didn't know that, thanks @Charlieface

Comment: See however https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753 one day we will get the `JSON_OBJECTAGG` function, which will do this automatically.